req.headers.authorization is set correctly on the client but undefined in the backend
I have an express/mongodB backend and a sveltekit frontend. In the frontend I want the user to be able to delete some items in the backend that belongs to him. To do so, I send a cookie to the client after the user logs in. However, I use server actions to delete the item, and from my research, the server cannot access cookies. So, I attach it in the headers inside actions like so
export const actions = 
{
 deleteItem: async({fetch,cookies}) => {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
   const cookie = cookies.get('jwt');
   headers.append('authorization', cookie);
   const response = await fetch('path-to-backend',{
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers,
      credentials: "include"
   })
   }
}

In the above code, I tested the cookie value as
console.log(cookie);

and it provides a value (the correct value). In the backend, I have an auth middleware to check the jwt token. In it I check the headers as
console.log(req.headers);

and I get an object that has "authorization" key with the token as a value. However, when I try to access the authorization value as req.headers['authorization'], I get undefined.
Why?
EDIT: To have more information, I am including some code. I have this code in a route called dashboard. In this route (+page.sevelte) I have budgets which I display like this (I fetch these data from the backend in the load function and it works fine)
<div class="grid">
          {#each budgets as budget}
          <Card budget={budget}/>
          <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value={budget._id}>
            <button formaction="?/deleteBudget">Delete</button>
          </form>
</div>

In the +page.server.ts I have this actions code
export const actions = {
  deleteBudget: async ({ request, url, cookies }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const budgetId = data.get("id");
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const jwt = cookies.get("jwt");
    if (jwt) {
      headers.append("Authorization", jwt);
      let response;

      response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/budget/${budgetId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers,
        credentials: "include",
      });


      if (response.ok) {
        location.reload();
        // throw redirect(302, "/dashboard");
      } else {
        const data = await response.json();

        return {
          status: 400,
          body: {
            success: false,
            error: data.message,
          },
        };
      }
    }
  },
};

but in the backend I get undefined for the token in req.headers.authorization.

Are you sure that you are properly configure middleware for parsing json i.e. app.use(express.json()); and app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));.Can you please also share your backend code where middleware check for jwt token?

@Subha In the backend I just access req.headers.authorization like this. It's undefined. The functionality of the middle ware is good, and it's working when I access other protected routes. I included more code in the frontend.

Please see below a minimal reproducible example showing your code has no issues to get the job done.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));

app.delete('/a', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Authorization : ${req.headers['authorization']}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

index.htm
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Authorization header check
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    const headers = new Headers();
    const para = document.querySelector('p');
    headers.append('authorization', 'some jwt content');
    fetch('a', {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          para.textContent = 'Error :' + response.status;
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        para.textContent = data;
      });
  </script>
</html>

Testing result


Thank you. Could you re-write it in sveltekit with server actions? I have a problem when I use server actions, I believe

Sorry, I do not work with it. One thing possible may be that please compare the two requests go to the server - the request from the above code, and the same from your sveltekit code. You may be able to spot some differences and fix it in your sveltekit code. As you know, the Network tab in Google Chrome Developer console  has options to inspect the requests in detail.
